# How does one position an orthographic camera for a side view centered in the viewport?

Tags: three.js

I have an object in the viewport, and the object is not centered around 0, 0, 0.

I'd like to position an orthographic camera so that I get a centered side view of the object.

Right now I'm positioning the camera at a fixed distance from the object and having it look at the midpoint of the bounding box.

```
// midpoint is the center of the bbox of the object
camera.position.set(-100, 0, -midpoint.z)
camera.lookAt(midpoint)
```

but this doesn't give me a straight side view. In particular, it looks like doing this

```
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)
```

makes absolutely no difference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say *why*, without looking into your code. The parts of code, that you provided are not sufficient to figure it out.

However making side view is somewhat trivial, you can find example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/Lphjwvzq/

```js
var renderer;
var camera;
var controls;
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var width = 10;
var height = 10;
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(width / -2, width / 2, height / 2, height / -2, 1, 1000);
scene.add(camera);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xffffff));
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera.position.x = 15;
camera.position.y = 0;
camera.position.z = 0;
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);
var size = 10;
var divisions = 10;
var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
scene.add(gridHelper);
var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  // controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};
animate();
```